# change date format Y-m-d H:i:s from json feed with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have got a problem with converting the date format from **Y-m-d H:i:s** to **dd-MM-YYYY** by using JQUERY.

My json looks like:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "posts": [
    { 
      "id": "21",
      "title": "Title",
      "date": "2013-06-26 06:46:29"
    }
  ]
}
```

And ajax request:

```
       $.ajax({ 
        url: ,
        async: false,
        callback: 'callback',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 2000,
        success: function (data, status) {


           if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {

            $('#news').append('<a class="item" href="single.html?type=news&id=' + item.id + '">' + item.title  + item.date + '</a>');
           }    
        }
 });
```

Can anyone kindly help me by using jsfiddle? I am new to jquery....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the `split` function in pure JavaScript, and toss the varaibles around.

```
var date = "2013-06-26 06:46:29";
var dateSplit = date.split(" ");
var dateSplit2 = dateSplit[0].split("-");
var formattedDate = dateSplit2.reverse().join('-');   // 26-06-2013
```

This might seems a but ugly, and it is. But it suits, as long as you don't actually need to format the date in other ways (like timezone and such). Then you'd have to look into the `Date()` object.

**EDIT:** I want to encourage people to use as much pure JavaScript as possible, due to it's speed. Often jQuery libraries and functions is filled with overhead, which causes your site to not only *load* slow, but also *process* slow. There are no short-cuts to the perfect code, you'll have to spend some time with it, and learn some tips and tricks. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$.datepicker.formatDate` like:

```
var oldDate = "2013-06-26 06:46:29";
console.log(oldDate);    //    2013-06-26 06:46:29

var newDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "dd-mm-yy", new Date(oldDate) );
console.log(newDate);    //    26-06-2013
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNW7K/)

Comment: Thank you Palash Mondal. I prefer do not use Jquery UI to save traffic.

Comment: That's ok. I just wanted to let you know about it, so that might help in your future endeavors may be. It's always better to know all the options you have. :)

Comment: That's very true! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse date string "2013-06-26 06:46:29" and format it. You can try this:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format